# Can I start my Laravel server using memory database?

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-artisan

Can I use memory to migrate my database and start the server?

My/config/database.php

```
'sqlite' => array(
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => ':memory:', // fail
    // 'database' => 'database', // success 
    'prefix' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
),
```

And Migrate table and start laravel serve

```
$ php artisan migrate:refresh 
$ php artisan serve
```

I use driver=sqlite + database=database every work fine,

I use driver=sqlite + database=:memory, the error message came from 127:0.0.1 said the database tables have not been created.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? As the name suggests, these databases live in memory. As soon as the migration process finishes, the in-memory database would be destroyed.

Comment: Because I have API server and WWW server, I would like to start my API Server with memory database, then I can do Browser Test (HTTP request) from www to API server. So that I can Ctrl+C to stop API server without saving any thing in API database.

Comment: Just use an SQlite database. Migrate it when starting your server, and delete it after stopping the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, since the migrate command will open one database connection and then serve will have one or more new connections.

> The database ceases to exist as soon as the database connection is
>   closed. Every :memory: database is distinct from every other. So,
>   opening two database connections each with the filename ":memory:"
>   will create two independent in-memory databases.
>
> https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: I wonder why Unit test can use driver=sqlite + database=:memory , but my web server cannot use

Comment: Your unit tests all run on the same process, using the same database connection

Comment: So that php artisan serve cannot receive the memory database which created by previous command ?

Comment: According to the link, separate connections can only share an in-memory database if they're in the same process. Since `migrate` is one process and `serve` is another, I don't believe that can work

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who want to do this for fast debugging, you can set the sqlite database file to `/tmp` directory. For example:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=/tmp/example-database.sqlite
```